# How to switch local branches various scenario

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash, git-add

I need to have some strategies while using Git as my version control.
Following are few scenarios while using local branches.
Can someone, please, explain how can I deal with those:
A and B are local branches X is remote branch

1. A is pulled from X, made some changes. Not staged,not committed,not pushed.
   How to switch to branch B without discarding changes of A but not including them in B
2. A is pulled from X, made some changes.Few unstaged(yes/no), Staged changes,not committed,not pushed.
   How to switch to branch B without discarding changes of A but not including them in B
3. A is pulled from X, made some changes.Few unstaged(yes/no), Staged changes,committed changes,not pushed.
   How to switch to branch B without discarding changes of A but not including them in B
4. A is pulled from X, made some changes. Want to keep a copy of these changes and want to work simultaneously on other 2 features on top of changes in A
   (the reason I'm working on multiple features simultaneously is because I might be waiting to hear from someone for further approach in that feature and dont wanna waste time)
5. A is pulled from X, made some changes. A is pushed to remote. Want an older version without these changes to go for another approach for same feature. Two sub scenarios here:

   1. No changes have been pushed by anyone after A is pulled from X and before I pushed A back to remote.
   2. someone pushed new code after A is pulled from X and before I pushed A back to remote.

It might be true that few cases have same solution and few cases might be moot/invalid but m posting them for the sake of understanding why are they moot/invalid and for the sake completeness.
On high level I'm trying to understand the behavior of stash,staging an commit and to have some handy reference instead of spending my dev hours juggling with git so that I can work on different features at any point of time. 
I would prefer not to create new workspace(eclipse)/working directory(Git) as a part of solution.

Comment: You should do your homework or at least provide examples of what you have tried. Git has some really awesome documentation.. http://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-cheat-sheet/  http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Answer (score 0):

Here are your answers:

1. There are two general strategies for switching to another branch while your working directory is not clean.  The first (and conceptually the easiest) option is to do a `git stash` on Branch A.  This will place all the changes (staged **and** unstaged) since your last commit into a stash object which can then be applied later.  The second option is to do a `git commit`.  Although it seems like the second option violates your question, bear with me for a moment.  When you return to Branch A at a later time, you can continue working and then commit those new changes using `git commit --amend`.  The history of A will be clean in that it won't have a separate commit for the earlier changes.
2. 3. and 4. See the answer to 1 above.
3. If you want to work on A from an earlier commit, you can checkout that earlier commit.  Typically you would want to create a new branch in this scenario, so the command `git checkout <SHA-1> -b newA`, where `SHA-1` is the hash of the earlier commit, will do the trick.
   With regard to your 2 sub-cases, it actually won't matter whether someone else pushes new changes to the HEAD of A on the remote or not.  The reason is that your new branch `newA` (based on an earlier commit of A) will be a rewrite of history.  The only way you will ever be able to push this new branch to the remote as A is by doing a `git push --force`.

As @cjm628 mentioned, you should really spend some time reading the Git documentation, but hopefully this answer will give you a good starting point.